# Extracting data from XML Nodes

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2012, xml-parsing

I am testing this simple script and just wondering why it didn't work.

```
DECLARE @myDoc xml  
DECLARE @ProdID int  

SET @myDoc = 
    '<Datatype xmlns="V8_0_1" id="113" name="PF_CleaningMode" hdl="47/4/SB8_3-910-8243-19/0/113" odobjid="915">
         <Datatypevalue id="2" name="Intermittent" />
         <Datatypevalue id="1" name="Continuous" />
         <Datatypevalue id="0" name="Off" />
     </Datatype>'  

SET @ProdID =  @myDoc.value('(Datatype/@id)[1]', 'int' )  
SELECT @ProdID
```

Hope you can assist. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just **simply ignoring** the default XML namespace that's defined on your `<Datatype>` node:

```
<Datatype xmlns="V8_0_1" id="113" name="PF_CleaningMode" 
          **************
```

You need to include that in your query!

Like this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'V8_0_1')
SELECT  @myDoc.value('(Datatype/@id)[1]', 'INT')
```

and you'll get the expected output of

```
113
```

Comment: Thank you ! ... I am not aware that I need to include NameSpace into my script. It works now.